# Google App Engine: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Query$Filter

Tags: java, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, google-cloud-platform

I'm getting this error in production only - the development server works fine.

An older version of my app works fine in production as well - but every time I do a new deployment I get this error when I access my app.
I tried to recompile the particular class where the error is thrown and to change the code, but still no luck.

I'm not really sure, but I guess it has something to do with the deployment process itself .. I'm deploying from Eclipse. I'm using:

- Eclipse Version: Oxygen.3 Release (4.7.3)
- Google Cloud Tools SDK 194.0.0
- App Engine 1.9.63

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Here is some simple test code:

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws IOException {
    res.setContentType("text/plain");
    res.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    // this throws: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - only in PRODUCTION
    Query.Filter filter = Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL.of("name", null);

    res.getWriter().print("Hello App Engine: " + filter);
}
```

This fails in production but works on the development server!

**Update 2:**
Opened an issue with Google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76144204

Comment: Why down vote?? The **Query.Filter** class is not found .. how can this be ??

Comment: Provide the full stacktrace as well.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I started getting this error today. When I deploy to AppEngine, I get NoClassDefFoundError on com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Query$Filter. It was working fine before and I don't think I changed anything.

Comment: @pldenc44: no solution yet - updated the description with the link to the Google issue

Comment: I was able to get past this issue by updating my Google Cloud SDK and upgrading to JAVA8 runtime. I'm not sure which one did the trick, but I'd say running "gcloud components update" is a good place to start.

Comment: +1 from me - there's a definite problem with app engine deployment at the moment. Thanks for setting up the Google Issue Tracker bug too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Google issue which is currently being looked into:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76144204

The fix for the moment is to copy appengine-api-1.0-sdk-1.9.63.jar file into the WEB-INF/lib directory as explained in this comment:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/76144204#comment45